# How to remove the inner units in a compound list in Python?

Tags: python

```
x = [['a','b'],['c','d','g'],['e','f','h','i','j'].......['zzy','xxx']]
```

If I got a compound list like this (a large list) in Python, how can I elegantly remove only, say, the element 'c' without removing the whole element ['c','d','g'] together? 
Obviously merely list.remove() doesn't work for this, and implementing a for loop works

```
for i in x:
    for j in i:
        if j == 'c':
           i = i.remove(j)
```

but is computationally expensive since it's a very long list...

thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: your question leaves a lot to be interpreted by us. Do you want this to be applicable only to this small list? why is 'a' a smaller unit than 'b'? 'a' and 'b' are strings. You also didn't provide anything you have tried so far.

Comment: Is the list always 2-d or can it be arbitrarily deep?

Comment: My apology. I'm new to Python and am not fully used to asking here. I've edited it a little and if you could have some look i'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only improvement I could find to your code is:

```
x = [['a','b'],['c','d','g'],['e','f','h','i','j'],['zzy','xxx']]

def remove(compound_list, elem):
    for lst in compound_list:
        for ix, item in enumerate(lst):
            if item == elem:
                del lst[ix]
remove(x, 'c')
```

It is slow O(n^2) but it is faster that first solution which counting `i.remove(j)` it's O(n^3)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the "smallest" element using `min` (provide a custom key function if you want to change the definition of smallest).

An *O(n)* solution (where *n* is the total number of elements in all the lists) can be to rebuild each list by omitting the smallest element:

```
x = [['a','b'],['b','b'],['c','c']]

smallest = min(min(l) for l in x)

x = [[e for e in l if e != smallest] for l in x]
print(x)
# [['b'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c']]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! but it's actually a very long list so using loop may cost much time..i've edited the question to make it clearer

Comment: @D.Chain I've updated the answer to not use remove since, as you rightly pointed out, it is computationally expensive to call it on each list. A computationally (in terms of time) more efficient alternative can be to rebuild the lists.